# to the gallon or by the gallon?

Tags: prepositions, measure-expressions

Why is the preposition "to," rather than "by" used in the following?

> This car does about 40 miles **to** the gallon.

Consider also this:

> He is paid 20 dollars **by** the hour.

Why is "by" rather than "to" used here?

Comment: Can you give contexts where these are from, especially the second one. I would have said miles per gallon and dollars per hour.

Comment: That is why I asked for context as what I say in the UK may not be what is used where you are. The standard abbreviation in the UK is mpg and we usually quote payments as per week, per month. In the US and elsewhere it may be different of course. I am an L1 speaker of the dialect spoken in southern England but that may be irrelevant.

Comment: If you do a wild-card search in Google NGrams for [miles * the gallon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=miles+%2A+the+gallon&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmiles%20%2A%20the%20gallon%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmiles%20to%20the%20gallon%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmiles%20on%20the%20gallon%3B%2Cc0) you'll see it's almost always ***to*** (very rarely, ***on***, which I think may be a US dialectal variant).  Note that your "paid $20 by the hour" isn't idiomatically valid anyway. *He's paid **by the** hour* OR with an amount: *He's paid $20 **an** hour*.

Comment: In principle, either or both of the cited contexts could feature ***for*** or ***per*** instead of ***by / to** [the]*. The specific prepositions we *do* use are "accidents of history" in many context anyway, so there's not necessarily any "reason" for the versions that are currently in use.

Comment: I found this sentence: “As you know, shipping has already been disrupted and there is a loss of billions of dollars **by** the hour. "

Comment: Finding random sentences on the Internet but not saying where you found them means users cannot know for certain if the writer is a native speaker or not. Even if the sentences are grammatical it's always best to see what the context is. In brief: A more academic and thoughtful approach will lead to better answers IMO.

Answer (score 2):

“He earns twenty dollars by the hour” means: He is paid hourly, and he made a total of 20 dollars. We don’t know how many hours he worked for that money.

If you wanted to say that he is making twenty dollars in one hour you’d say “he makes twenty dollars per hour” or “twenty dollars an hour”. The “to” in “40 miles to the gallon” comes from the fact that the gallons actually produce the mileage. The hours don’t produce anything, it’s the work done in this hour.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the preposition "to," rather than "by" used in the following?
>
> This car does about 40 miles to the gallon.

No reason, it's just an idiom. **"a"** or **"per"** could replace "to the" and would also be natural.

> Consider also this:
>
> He is paid 20 dollars by the hour.
>
> Why is "by" rather than "to" used here?

Neither "by" nor "to" sounds natural. Usually we would say "He is paid 20 dollars **an hour**" or **"per hour".**

**"paid by the hour"** is usually used like this:

> He is paid by the hour.

without a dollar amount. It means he is paid according to how many hours he works, not a fixed salary.

Comment: How about "He earns 20 dollars by the hour"?